# Netbeans while/for blocks to collapse folding

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I use netbeans 8 rc1 , as older version, netbeans does not fold while/for blocks, is there any way to do enable this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible in java (and c/c++) at the moment (see enhancement bugs [#209041](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209041), [#222493](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222493), [#233225](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233225) and [#209784](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209784)).

As a workaround you can use NB's code folding:

```
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="An example of a loop">
while( what != ever )
{
   ever++;
}
//</editor-fold>
```

Just mark the code you want to wrap into a folding and click on the yellow "hint bulb" and you can select folding there.

Btw, you can change the values of `defaultstate` and `desc`.